# Android BlackScreen Layout after showing Activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, xml-layout

After starting the application on mobile , the Layout background go to black after changing from one activity to another

NOTE : the origin color of the layout is White

this is the screen-shot :

first activity  :

[image]

second activity :

[image]

Here is the XML Code :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#EAF6FB"
    tools:context=".devisgris">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tolbare"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#fff"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewsinstre1"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="177dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.358"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/image2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonsinstre11"
        android:layout_width="209dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#009cb4"
        android:text="Choisir image"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.773" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonsinstre1"
        android:layout_width="166dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/suivant"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.926"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.946" />

    <Button

        android:layout_width="209dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#ed6e1d"
        android:onClick="take"
        android:text="Prendre image"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.642" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView34"
        android:layout_width="201dp"
        android:layout_height="73dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Cart gris recto"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.1" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

i try to make a double refresh in the "OnCreate" function for the layout but its random.

Thank You

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Black Screen between Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34353034/android-black-screen-between-activity)

Comment: please add the code that you are using to switch between activities

Comment: Android I will test that solution and i will give you my feedback

Comment: Android ► im using the same strategy in the poste bellow

Pooja Rajendran C ► the code that i use is the same as in the post that Android give me , i will make a screenshot of the screen to give you a better picter of the issu

Comment: Can you post the XML's?

Comment: @gratienasimbahwe i add the XML code

Comment: thank you @UsefGeoso, i don't see the xml for the second activity

Comment: its the same XML, only the "tools:context" is changed to ".gris2"

Comment: Can you show me your .java file of this layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed the probleme it was an issu into the Gardle version , i make an Upgrade of it