# Understanding Window#getSharedElementTransition()

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

I have two Activities `A` and `B` which have a SharedElement. If `Activity A` starts `Activity B` and listens to the the transition, both the listener for exit and reenter are called.

Here the code for the calling `Activity A`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        getWindow().getSharedElementReenterTransition().addListener(new Transition.TransitionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTransitionStart(Transition transition) {
                Log.i("Log", "A REENTER");
            }

            ...
        });

        getWindow().getSharedElementExitTransition().addListener(new Transition.TransitionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTransitionStart(Transition transition) {
                Log.i("Log", "A EXIT");
            }

           ...
        });

        getWindow().getSharedElementEnterTransition().addListener(new Transition.TransitionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTransitionStart(Transition transition) {
                Log.i("TestApp", "A ENTER");


            }

            ...
        });
        getWindow().getSharedElementReturnTransition().addListener(new  Transition.TransitionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTransitionStart(Transition transition) {
                Log.i("TestApp", "A RETURN");
            }

            ...
        });


    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Act2.class);
        Pair<View, String> pair1 = Pair.create(findViewById(R.id.textView), findViewById(R.id.textView).getTransitionName());
        ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, pair1);
        startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
    }
}
```

If I now execute `onClick()` (to start `Activity B`) and then hit the back button to return to `Activity A`, the Log will be as follows:

```
A REENTER
A EXIT
B ENTER
B RETURN
B ENTER
B RETURN
A REENTER
A EXIT
```

I would expect it to be

```
A EXIT
B ENTER
B RETURN
A REENTER
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, the same transition is used for both the exit and reenter transitions as well as the enter and return transitions. If you explicitly set them, they will be different.

I believe that you are adding listeners to the same transition, so they are all being called.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Even though I read a couple of times that they are the same if not explicitly set, I didn't imagine that both listeners would be called. Seems weird

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the similar problem and found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27346020/understanding-exit-reenter-shared-element-transitions)

> There is a bug in Lollipop that causes the shared element return transition to be interrupted if it takes longer than the reenter
>   transition duration. If you adjust your reenter transition duration
>   (on the calling Activity), that should fix the interruption problem.

You better use the **enter** and **return** shared element transitions.

Comment: My transitions consist of nothing more than the code above. So they should not take long. Also how does that help me if I need to have the possibility to do different things during onExit and onReenter? [I adjusted the original post, to provide more information. ]